# Sharepoint Add-in Calendar Format Broken in Default.aspx in Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, sharepoint-calendar

I am attempting to add a calendar to my Default.aspx in my sharepoint hosted add-in in visual studio. I used the default code-snippet for adding sharepoint lists. Here's what I added to my Default.aspx:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="Default" ID="full" Title="loc:full">
    <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server"
        ListUrl="Lists/Calendar"
        IsIncluded="True"
        JsLink="clientTemplate.js"
        NoDefaultStyle="TRUE"
        PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW"
        Default="False"
        ViewContentTypeId="0x">
    </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

and this is the result...

[image]

Pretty dang ugly if you ask me. How can I get this looking like a normal share point calendar instead of an unusable mess?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you are missing all the css.

Comment: @Christoffer Thanks! Any idea where I can find the CSS for a calendar?

Comment: For the simplicity, i would include SharePoint core15 CSS as all the calendars styling are included there. To me it looks like you are missing other important controls, like the ability to sort between months.

Answer (score 0):

Create an OOTB page in SharePoint site and add a calendar webpart in the page. Save this page.

Open the page in SharePoint Designer and copy the calendar webpart related code. Place the copied code in your default.aspx page.

This might be helpful.